# Is there a way to Manually unlock the Opentext Exstream Design Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, opentext, hp-exstream

I have encountered an error after attempting DB Maintenance from within Design Manager, and cannot figure out how to get the DB unlocked.

Essentially, ran the DB check for errors utility, and during that process, many errors were thrown. When the utility stopped, I closed it, and eventually design manager. When I tried to log back in, I am getting the "This database has been locked for Database Maintenance..." error as shown in the image.  The database should have been unlocked when I closed the utility, but it seems to have persisted.

Does anyone have any experience in this/a way to manually unlock the database?

My next step will be to install a backup of the database and hope that this fixes the issue, but I am hoping to find someone who may have encountered this to find an already tested solution as I am a bit in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is simple process:

1. open Design Manager and connect to your database
2. open Environment / System / System settings,
3. On Basic tab, there is a "System Status" drop down, change from "Locked" to "Normal"
4. Save System Settings.
   This should reset the database back to unlocked status.